# Draw time series of three or more variables on one chart in R

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart

To limit number of charts and help to analyse more than one variable at the time, I am using the *twoord.plot* function from the [plotrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/index.html) package:

```
labels <- list("var1" = expression(paste("my Variable ", kg/m^2)),"var2" = expression(paste("Something ", kg/m^2)))

lx <- myVariables[[period]][["Date"]]
ly <- myVariables[[period]][[var1]]
ry <- myVariables[[period]][[var2]]

at_x <- lx[seq(1,length(lx),5)]

twoord.plot(lx,ly,lx,ry,xticklab=format(as.Date(at_x,"%d-%m-%Y"),"%b %Y"),xtickpos=at_x, main=paste(t_labels[[var1]], "and", t_labels[[var2]],sep=" ")
```

It works really great, but I wish to add third variable, probably as a points, to this chart. It seems that I will need another Y-axis for mentioned data (or multiply them, so that their range will match one of the *var1* or *var2*).

What is the best way to do that? There's no threeord.plot function.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make a minimal reproducible example?